# link twig template in a tag

Tags: templating, routes

I created two twig templates: `home.twig` and `about.twig`.
in home.twig it's this code:

```
<a href="/about">go to about template</a>
```

and in about.twig it's:

```
<h1>about</h1>
```

when I click "go to about template" it shows 404 error but, when I go to `http://MY_HOST/about` it shows me the about template.
how to link this templates? thank's

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the URL of the page, where the link to /about is shown?
2. Make sure you do not have a  tag in the source of the page
3. Make sure you are not switching from http:// to https:// (SSL), which could also cause the 404 if the host is not available on http:// AND https://